# Invalid column names in postgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql

I have recently started using PostgreSQL (V15.5 64-bit) and found that the following command generates an error:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table_x1 (
    info TEXT,
    folder TEXT,
    analyse TEXT,
    status TEXT,
);
```

The problem is with the  'analyse' column name.

Are there any other column names that should be avoided?

Comment: you can find all reserved words in the docs https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-keywords-appendix.html

Comment: Many thanks. Your link needs to be changed to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-keywords-appendix.html